# Event click from google chart blocks pop-ups when I try to open a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-visualization

An event click from a Google chart blocks pop-ups when I try to open a new window.

This is how I draw the chart:

```
    printChart: function() {
        var self = this;

        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            'packages': ['corechart'],
            "callback": function() {
                try {
                    showLoading('widget');

                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Classification');                     
                    data.addColumn('number', $.t('columnVisits'));
                    data.addColumn('number', $.t('columnContacted'));
                    data.addColumn('number', $.t('columnUnattended'));
                    data.addColumn('number', '');
                    data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'annotation' });


                    //We add all the elements to the graph
                    var dataClassified = self.getClassifiedFromConfig();

                    _.each(dataClassified, function(element) {
                        var inactive = (element.Inactive <= 0 && element.Visits <= 0 && element.ActivitiesPhoneCalls <= 0) ? 1 : element.Inactive,
                            assigned = element.Assigned > 0 ? element.Assigned : 1;

                        data.addRow([
                                    {
                                        v: element.IdClassification.toString(),
                                        f: element.Classification
                                    },
                                    element.Visits/assigned,
                                    element.ActivitiesPhoneCalls/assigned,
                                    inactive/assigned,
                                    0, //empty column for placing the Cycle as an annotation at the end of the stacked bars.
                                    element.Cycle + ' ' + $.t('days')
                        ]);
                    });

                    var options = {
                        isStacked: true,
                        hAxis: {
                            format: '#%',
                            minValue: 0,
                            maxValue: 1,
                            textStyle: {
                                color: '#404040',
                                fontName: 'Roboto',
                                fontSize: 14
                            }
                        },
                        vAxis: {
                            textStyle: {
                                color: '#404040',
                                fontName: 'Roboto',
                                fontSize: responsiveFontSize
                            }
                        },
                        bar: {
                            groupWidth: '75%'
                        },
                        annotations: {
                            alwaysOutside: true,
                            stemColor: 'none', // eliminate the tick for the annotation
                            textStyle: {
                                fontName: 'Roboto',
                                fontSize: 14,
                                bold: false,
                                italic: false,
                                color: '#404040'
                            }
                        },
                        series: {
                            3: {
                                visibleInLegend: false 
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'top'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            trigger: 'none'
                        },
                        height: responsiveHeight,
                        width: '100%',
                        colors: ['#85ac1f', '#fccd3d', '#eaeaea'],
                        enableInteractivity: true
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('portfolio-coverage-chart'));

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(e){
                        self.mouseOverHandler(chart, data);
                    });

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e){
                        self.selectHandler(chart, data);
                    });

                    /*$('.portfolio-coverage-chart').on('click', function() {
                        self.selectHandler(chart, data);
                    });*/

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("error printChart " + e);
                } finally {
                    hideLoading('widget');
                }

            }
        });
    },
```

When the user clicks in a bar of my Google chart I call this event:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e){
                            self.selectHandler(chart, data);
                        });
```

The "selectHandler" function:

```
    selectHandler: function(chart, data) {
        var self = this;
        var id = 5;
        var customView = "";
        var elementClick = chart.getSelection();

        if (elementClick.length > 0){
            var row = elementClick[0].row,
                column = elementClick[0].column;

            if (column === 1) {
                id = 5;
                customView = "customview.visitcompanies";
            } else if (column === 2) {
                id = 6;
                customView = "customview.contactcompanies";
            } else if (column === 3) {
                id = 7;
                customView = "customview.unattendedcompanies";
            } else {
                return;
            }

            //nulls out the selection so we can select it again
            chart.setSelection();

            var idClassification = parseInt(data.getValue(row, 0));
            var params = self.setParams(idClassification);

            doDrilldown(id, customView, "companies", params);
        }
    }
```

And then, the "doDrillDown" method try to open a new window applying the window.open function:

```
// open entity page
var newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
if (newTab) {
    newTab.focus();
} else {
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

But the pop-ups of my website get blocked before opening a new window.

If instead of the event handler from google I call an on click event works as expected (the problem here is that the data from "chart.getSelection();" is not update, and I get the selection done before the last one):

```
$('.portfolio-coverage-chart').on('click', function() {
                            self.selectHandler(chart, data);
                        });
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you show a bit more of what's going on?  I'm presuming that these things are in some form of click event.  If that's the case, by being able to see the click event setup, it might be possible to figure out why the Google chart event click is interfering with the popup code.

Comment: @AndrewGray, I edited my question with more information months ago. Do you know what's happening?